# How do I extract the HTML source of a website in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xcode

I'm using Xcode to build an app to monitor a web page to see if the HTML changes. I want to extract a website's HTML source to compare it to the same website's HTML source at a later time to see if the website has changed. I can't find anything that would allow me to do this.

If it's not possible to extract the HTML of a site, I need some way to check for changes in the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to retrieve the page as an NSData instance, and save it in an ivar (for example). Then retrieve it again into another NSData instance and compare the two instances using [NSData isEqualToData:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: That works great! Thanks for the help; I understood how to compare the data, I just didn't know how to get it.

Comment: For any googlers, using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` should also work